# pv command for progress bar not working correctly in a script

Tags: bash, shell, pv

I have a script to perform a synchronisation between the local and production databases. In this script, there is a command to import the `production.sql` to my development database. It's a bit long, so I would like to add a progress bar.

The command works when I type it directly in my terminal, but when it's executed by the script, I can see the progress bar, but it's doesn't progress. It remains at 0% until the end of the progression.

[image: no progress]
This the part of my script:

```
log "Restore DB..."
if brew ls pv > /dev/null; then
    pv tmp/$dump | mysql -u rails_bots -h 127.0.0.1 -prails_bots $database < tmp/$dump
else
    mysql -u rails_bots -h 127.0.0.1 -prails_bots $database < tmp/$dump
fi
```

Do you know why it doesn't work in my script?

Comment: I am confused about `< tmp/$dump`. Is it required in line #3?

Comment: @gudok `tmp/$dump` is the path to the sql file that I import. `$dump` is defined above in my script

Comment: Why do you specify it twice? Once as an argument to `pv`, second time with `<`?

Comment: Oh, in the exemple that I saw, it was like this. But I just tested without `< tmp/$dump` and the import works but not the progress bar

Comment: Oops my bad it works, thank you @gudok!